# Character '<' in command prompt

Tags: c++, file, class, oop, output

I have a program I am writing, I have already completed it, but the requirement/specification for it says that:

In the "Command Prompt", if someone runs your program like this:

```
Peter David < savednames.txt
```

it should print out the names inside `savednames.txt` that matches each of "Peter" and "David"

I have written the program but my own is interactive, i.e it asks for the file, then the name you want to search for, and then it prints the matches.

It works perfectly fine, but I don't understand what the running of the program in command prompt like this: `"Peter David < savednames.txt"` means. I am using C++ on Microsoft Windows.

Please I need your help to explain it and how to implement it in my code...is it some kind of operator overloading or ...I don't understand!

Comment: most shells use this notation to feed your program's standard input with the contents of the specified file. so just read from the standard input.

Comment: Thanks for the editing... this is my first time using stackoverflow :)

Comment: I think what the specification means is if the program name is xxx.bat, then you'd have to type **xxx Peter David < savednames.txt**.  In that case, you can grab Peter, David and anything else as parameters and whatever is in savednames as input.

Comment: Thanks for the response. but what do they mean by the 'Peter' 'David'? are they parameter arguments that I need to implement in my code or what? ....gosh! I'm so confused...  :(

Comment: exactly cup! you understand the specification very well... how do I do it...

Comment: The exact word in the specification is:  Running your program from the command-line like this:
MyProgram Jones Winton < surnames.txt
Should print out:
Jones: Jonas, Johns, Saunas 
Winton: Van Damme   ...(I'm sorry I don't know how to add a new line in typing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
yourprogramname Peter David < savednames.txt
```

means that your program will be called with Peter as first argument, David as second argument, and its *standard input* will be connected to a stream reading out of `savednames.txt`.

You just need to read standard input one row at a time, and process it according to the arguments you received.

You just need to modify the code you already have to take the names from the command line (is there a limit? Could there be *three* names? Or four? You need to consider that) and to read the data from standard input stream, without any need of opening a file.

Comment: Great!...I think I'm getting something, can std::vector<string> work as the argument(s)? so that they can request for any amount of names they want? ...or am I heading towards the bush like that?

Comment: ...or will I have my program to be something like :  Myclass::MyFunction(vector<string>, string) where the 'vector' will be the Peter and David, and savednames.txt will be the 2nd argument 'string'.

Comment: @user3599953 The program arguments are accessed in `main()` using its second argument `argv` (which is an array of `char*`). The user can input as many arguments as he wants and `argv` will hold them. You have the option of copying the arguments from `argv` over to an `std::vector<std::string>` but its not required to allow variable number of arguments.

Comment: I'll follow your comments and keep trying/testing it to see what comes out of it...Thank you very much... Thanks All! I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 4):

On the command line, `<` is used for input redirection.  The shell opens the file whose name follows the `<` and copies its contents into standard input for the program.

So if you called `program input.txt`, you could open the file and read its contents using `std::ifstream` or whatever; if you called `program < input.txt`, you could just read the file's contents from stdin using `cin`.

You can also do the same for output.  Instead of opening a file and writing to it in your code, write to stdout and call your program as `program > output.txt`.

Comment: If it is called with `program input.txt` he can access `input.txt` through `argv[1]`, correct?

Comment: @0x499602D2: Yes.  But if you call `program < input.txt`, neither the `<` nor the `input.txt` are in argv.

Comment: Thanks, but what about those 2 names in front of the character '<'?

Comment: @user3599953: They're just ordinary [command-line arguments](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DEN36Up4/). `argv[1]` will  be `Peter` and `argv[2]` will be `David`.

Comment: @user3599953 Those are the program arguments. They are accessed through the second argument of `main()` called `argv`. The first argument is path to the executable (`argv[0]`), but the rest are the program arguments (`argv[1] ... argv[n]`).